# How to debug connections to melpa with emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to add packages via melpa in my init file. It was working, but today it stopped. To debug, I started with "emacs -q" and typed the following into my scratch buffer:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

The first two lines seem to work. The third line gives me an error and stack trace:

```
(wrong-type-argument arrayp nil)
package--add-to-archive-contents(nil "melpa")
package-read-archive-contents()
```

Is the error with my setup? Do I have the wrong url for melpa? I'm using GNU Emacs 24.5.1.

Comment: From a quick look (my first time) at the package.el code, my _guess_ is that your `~/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/melpa/archive-contents` file might be corrupted, and it's not finding an `array` for an element. I _think_ it would be safe to delete that file because it's just a local cache that will get rebuilt?

Comment: That looks like it did the trick. Thanks!  If you change your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Happy to hear that. Answer added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although I'm not very familiar with it, I took a quick look at the `package.el` code.

My guess is that your `~/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/melpa/archive-contents` file is "corrupted". As a result, `package--add-to-archive-contents` is not finding an `array` for an element it would expect to get from that file.

I believe the `archive-contents` file is only a local cache. If you delete it, it will get rebuilt, and you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you for this it worked. I removed gnu and melpa-stable directories and restarted and it worked. Still not sure how the file got corrupted? Considering i have never touched that file.